# Infinite "Enter your gender (M/F): " when it's run. It doesn't accept any inputs and just asks again but there are 0 errors

Tags: python-3.x

When i run this code in pycharm edu 3.5.2, it asks for input over and over again. The section in **bold** is the part where I'm having trouble. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
# ASKS FOR PLAYER REGISTRATION:

    gender = input("Enter your gender (M/F): ")

# MAKES SURE THE USER INPUT WAS 'M', 'F', 'FEMALE', OR, 'MALE':

    if gender.upper not in ("M", "F", "MALE", "FEMALE"):
        while gender.upper not in ("M", "F", "MALE", "FEMALE"):
          gender = input("Enter your gender (M/F): ") <-------asks over and over for input
        break
```

Comment: `gender.upper` is a function.  That function is not in the tuple, so the loop will never terminate

Comment: what's a tuple?

Comment: A `tuple` is like a list that can't change.  `("M", "F", "MALE", "FEMALE")` is a tuple.  They are written as comma separated expressions inside parentheses. If you're new to python, or programming in general, I recommend reading through the official python tutorial.  It should give you an idea of what the basic tools of python are and when to use them. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: okay thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do `upper()` instead of `upper`.